# Build string from object properties in specific order

Tags: javascript

I have an object with the following data.
I want to build a string from it but I need it to be in a specific order.

```
  const info = {
    first: 'John',
    last: 'Doe',
    middle: 'Henry',
    suffex: 'Sr',
  }
```

result = John Henry Doe Jr

Here is what I have but I'd like to get rid of the if/else

```
  const name= `${info.first}${
    info.middle ? ' ' + info.middle : ''
  } ${info.last}${info.suffix ? ' ' + info.suffix : ''}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter an array with conditional chaining

```js
const names = infos
  .map(info => [info?.first, info?.middle, info?.last,info?.suffix].filter(val=>val)
  .join(' ')
  );
console.log(names)
```

```html
<script>
  const infos = [{
      first: 'John',
      last: 'Doe',
      middle: 'Henry',
      suffix: 'Sr'
    },
    {
      first: 'Jane',
      last: 'Doe',
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Alternatively use optional chaining, nullish coalescing operator and remove extra space using a RegExp

```js
const names = infos
  .map(info => `${info?.first ?? ''} ${info?.middle ?? ''} ${info?.last ?? ''} ${info?.suffix ?? ''}`
    .trim()
    .replace(/\s+/g,' ')
  );
console.log(names)
```

```html
<script>
  const infos = [{
      first: 'John',
      middle: 'Henry',
      last: 'Doe',
      suffix: 'Sr'
    },
    {
      first: 'Jane',
      last: 'Doe',
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Alternatively if the objects are in correct order

You map to an array and filter on empty

```js
const names = infos
  .map(info => Object.values(info)
    .filter(val => val)
    .join(' ')
  );
console.log(names)
```

```html
<script>
  const infos = [{
      first: 'John',
      middle: 'Henry',
      last: 'Doe',
      suffix: 'Sr'
    },
    {
      first: 'Jane',
      last: 'Doe',
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: Ah nice but this would not be in the correct order.

Comment: @me-me I had TWO solutions and one was and now they both are, if you cannot make the object in correct order then the first version works

Comment: Unfortunately the order of the object could vary because its coming from backend.

Comment: So use the first solution which will work every time

Comment: I added one more using RegExp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `?.` operator

```js
let info = {
    first: 'John',
    last: 'Doe',
    middle: 'Henry',
    suffix: 'Sr',
}
console.log(
  info?.first + " " + info?.middle + " " + info?.last + " " + info?.suffix
)   // "John Henry Doe Jr"


info = {
    first: 'Jane',
    last: 'Doe',
    middle: '',
    suffix: '',
}
console.log('>'+
  info?.first + " " + info?.middle + " " + info?.last + " " + info?.suffix
  +'<'
);  // "Jane  Doe "
```

Comment: That will make a lot of spaces

Comment: You're very right, that's my bad

Answer (score 0):

I like keeping the code very clear with intention and what it is trying to do, as below:

```js
const info = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Doe',
  middle: 'Henry',
  suffix: 'Sr'
};

function getName(obj) {
  const result = [];
  if (obj.first) result.push(obj.first);
  if (obj.middle) result.push(obj.middle);
  if (obj.last) result.push(obj.last);
  if (obj.suffix) result.push(obj.suffix);
  return result.join(' ');
}

console.log(getName(info));
```

Another way utilizing generators:

```js
const info = {
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Doe',
  middle: 'Henry',
  suffix: 'Sr'
};

function* getNames(obj) {
  if (obj.first) yield obj.first;
  if (obj.middle) yield obj.middle;
  if (obj.last) yield obj.last;
  if (obj.suffix) yield obj.suffix;
}

function getName(obj) {
  return [...getNames(obj)].join(' ');
}

console.log(getName(info));
```

Comment: Lol: `I'd like to get rid of the if/else`

Comment: @mplungjan https://xyproblem.info/